# Socket.io and react Router: how to reference browser history and other dependencies from socket handler?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-router

I have a react app that uses socket.io to interact with the backend. There is a scenario when the backend pushes a message that causes a page to change. Is there a way to reference react router history from the handler without having to wrap the whole app in a wrapper component? Please see below code sample.

Also, I have a follow up question regarding referencing dispatch. Currently, I keep the socket on the App state (I'm not using redux but I implemented a very basic hacky version using useContext and useReducer). So when I connect the socket, I'm able to set up handlers for different socket events and dispatch actions accordingly. However, I feel like socket connection should not be coupled to the Application state. Is there a way pass the app state's dispatch as a dependency without using a wrapper component? Currently I reference dispatch in a component this way:

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
```

code sample:

```
export function connectSocket() {

return async (dispatch) => {

const socket = await io.connect('', {
    path: '/socket.io/',
    secure: true,
    transports: ['websocket'],
  });

  socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
    socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
    socket.io.opts.pingTimeout = 30000;
  })


  // need to reference history here
  socket.on('nextpage', _ => {
       history.push('page');
  });

  // referencing dispatch
  socket.on('foo', _ => {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.foo,
      payload: _,
    });
  });
}
}
```

Thanks.